# Xcode: sqlite3_step returning 101, but not executing code within block

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have a block of code to execute if the sqlite3_step statement returns 101, but even though it is, the code within the block is being skipped.  Why would this be?

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Value: %li",(long)sender.tag);
    NSString *delete_feed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM user_data WHERE id = %li", (long)sender.tag];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [delete_feed UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"%d", sqlite3_step(statement));
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) { <== MY ISSUE
            NSLog(@"Got here"); <== NEVER GETS HERE
            for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
                if (subview.tag == 2) {
                    [subview removeFromSuperview];
                    [self createListPage];
                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `sqlite3_step` is returning `101`? `101` is `SQLITE_DONE`.

Comment: What does the immediately preceding NSLog for that same `_step` command say?

Comment: rmaddy and Nick, yes, when outputting from NSLog, the value returns 101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling sqlite3_step twice. I would think the first time it is SQLITE_DONE (101), but the 2nd time (when you are entering your block), it is returning some other error code.

May try something like (pseudo-code)

```
    int ret_code = sqlite3_step(statement);
    NSLog(@"ret_code=[%d]", ret_code);
    if(ret_code == SQLITE_DONE) {
       // do some stuff here...
    }
```

Comment: I'm only doing that to know what the code returned is.  When I remove that snippet, that same thing this happens.

Comment: Well, isn't that weird.  After trying you solution, it worked and went into the block of code.  I wonder why my other blocks, that do something similar, are working fine, but this one does not?  Eitherway, I've learned something.  Thanks